# How to integrate squareup payment method to get the nonce in react-native app?

Tags: react-native, square

I am working on the latest version of React-native. I cannot find any documentation to get the card nonce using the application_id and location_id of SquareUp. 
Please suggest me how to integrate this payment method with React-Native application.

Also, suggest me package works best for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this: https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payment-form/payment-form-walkthrough
up to step 1.3 to generate the nonce in html

Host this page on github pages and force it to server over https (http wont work with square)

Embed your github page in WebView React Native or Expo. Retrieve the nonce from WebView and pass it to your API where the rest can be taken care of with the square api.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Quick-Start](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/blob/master/react-native-in-app-payments-quickstart/) you'll find the method `onCardNonceRequestSuccess(cardDetails)` which is the callback for returning your information from Square. On that `cardDetails` parameter you'll find a key `"nonce"` that will contain your nonce that you need to send to your back end for processing.

```js
  async onCardNonceRequestSuccess(cardDetails) {
    if (this.chargeServerHostIsSet()) {
      try {
        await chargeCardNonce(cardDetails.nonce);
        SQIPCardEntry.completeCardEntry(() => {
          showAlert('Your order was successful',
            'Go to your Square dashbord to see this order reflected in the sales tab.');
        });
      } catch (error) {
        SQIPCardEntry.showCardNonceProcessingError(error.message);
      }
    } else {
      SQIPCardEntry.completeCardEntry(() => {
        printCurlCommand(cardDetails.nonce, SQUARE_APP_ID);
        showAlert(
          'Nonce generated but not charged',
          'Check your console for a CURL command to charge the nonce, or replace CHARGE_SERVER_HOST with your server host.',
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

[Link to repo of above code](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/blob/master/react-native-in-app-payments-quickstart/app/screens/HomeScreen.js#L193)

The example application should show most of what is necessary for integrating into a React Native application. The main piece that you need to change is the `chargeCardNonce()` function found [here](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/blob/master/react-native-in-app-payments-quickstart/app/service/Charge.js) to `POST` that nonce to your backend.

Comment: I am doing any payment here, I just want to get nonce on the basis of location_id and application_id. I am not able to get "nonce". Please suggest if you have any solution.

Comment: The only way to get a `nonce` is be using the [`startCardEntryFlow`](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/blob/master/docs/reference.md#startcardentryflow), [`requestApplePayNonce`](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/blob/master/docs/reference.md#requestapplepaynonce), or [`requestGooglePayNonce`](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/blob/master/docs/reference.md#requestgooglepaynonce). You can also get realtime assistance over at https://squ.re/slack

Comment: How to get on back arrow callback on square payment form and also set default postcode value in payment form.